# Duplicating XML Elements in InDesign, Images elements don't duplicate properly?

Tags: xml, tags, adobe-indesign

So I'm creating Multiple different documents for a set of 35 different people.  Business Cards, Post cards, etc.

So I'll use business cards as the example;

I'm importing Name, Phone # and email address AND their photo.

When I duplicate my tagged items (text box and image box)

The Image Tag is not duplicated it duplicates inside of the original Tag.

**Tag setup before duplication:**

Person
   First_Name
   Last_Name
   Email
   *Headshot* - this is an image box.

**Tag Setup after duplication**

Person
   First_Name
   Last_Name
   Email
   *Headshot - this is an image box.*
   *Headshot - this is an image box.*

Person
   First_Name
   Last_Name
   Email
   *- No Image box duplicated in tags!*

Am I just not nesting the Image tag properly for it to duplicate?
Or do i have to manually retag an image box each time?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in detail in the book A Designer's Guide to Adobe InDesign and XML.

Look at your XML source and make sure the image reference is in the same order as your placeholder layout. InDesign can only import xml in the same order as your data. If the data is out of order, you will need to use an XSLT to re-order the data elements.